# Get "error occurred while sending a request" in Windows Mobile 10 Emulator and Phone

Tags: wcf, service, uwp, emulation, windows-10-mobile

I get an error message "an error has occurred while sending a request" when my UWP app tries to communicate with a WCF Service Application (that retrieves info from a database server). This error occurs when the app/service combo runs in Windows Mobile 10 Emulator and phone. On the other hand, this combo of app/service runs fine in Local Machine (my Windows 10 desktop PC). Seem like the WCF service may not be running when the app/service is running in the emulator or the phone. I would like to fix this problem if this is possible. If this is not possible, please suggest an alternative.

What I am trying to accomplish is to use a Windows 10 phone to connect to our database server (SQL Server) (all in local WiFi network, not through internet) to view or to update data in the database. Unfortunately UWP doesn't allow UWP apps to connect to the database server directly as stated in this web page:

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-access-data-from-935e360c#content

According to that web page, I need to create a WCF Service Application as a middle-man between the UWP app and the database server. That is the reason why I need a WCF Service Application in addition to my UWP app.

Please note that I have tried the sample program in the web page shown above. Unfortunately, it has the same problem as my app.

As mentioned above, the sample program and my app both work fine in Local Machine (the database is in a database server that is not in the Local Machine). But both show the same error when they are running in Windows emulator or in a Windows phone.

I have tried to narrow this down by using a bare-bone WCF Service Application that doesn't connect to the database server to rule out the database connection has anything to do with this problem. The bare-bone WCF Service Application simply returns hardcoded test data to the UWP app. But it still has the same problem. This means the problem has nothing to do with database connection.

The bare-bone WCF Service Application is created using the WCF Service Application template. I have only renamed the classes (from Service1/IService to DbService/IDbService). Nothing to it.

The error is triggered in the GetDataAsync(...) statement in the example shown below. It is in OnLoaded() event handler of MainPage.xaml.cs of the UWP app:

```
private async void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
   try
      {
      RefDbService.DbServiceClient client1 = new RefDbService.DbServiceClient();
      String sTestMsg = await client1.GetDataAsync( 12345 );
         // The above statement triggers the error in Emulator or in phone.
      this.lblDebugMsg.Text = sTestMsg;
      }
   catch( Exception ex )
      {
      this.lblDebugMsg.Text = ex.Message;
      }
   }
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Jay Chan

Comment: Have you checked the network connection between your client and your server? It seems like a network issue.

Comment: Sorry that I probably was not clear in my original post.  The UWP and the WCF Service are running in the same device (Local Machine, or Windows Mobile 10 Emulator, or a real Windows 10 Phone).  But the database server is in a different computer (within the same local area network).  I have just changed my post to reflect this additional info.  In other words, this is not a network issue because the UWP and WCF Service has no problem retrieves info from the database server if the combo runs in Local Machine (the database server is in a different machine).

Comment: How did you host a WCF Service in Windows 10 Mobile? AFAIK, this is impossible as we can't run classic apps on Windows 10 Mobile by now. For a  common scenario, the WCF Service should be hosted on the server  such as the server host your database.

Comment: If I understand what you said correctly, I should move the WCF Service into a server and then ask the UWP app to communicate with the WCF Service. This sounds reasonable. I will try later this week to see how this works. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I have finally created a small sample program (WCF service and UWP app) that actually works.  If someone needs to do the same thing, you need to following this tutorial https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733766(v=vs.110).aspxto learn how to

Comment: I have finally created a small sample program (WCF service and UWP app) that actually works.  If someone needs to do the same thing, you need to following this tutorial https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733766(v=vs.110).aspx to learn how to write a WCF service that works with console application, and then following this web page https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733766(v=vs.110).aspx to learn the way to convert it into a WCF service application running under IIS.  Remember to update the service-reference of the app whenever you change the configuration of the WCF service.

Comment: If you've solved the problem, you can answer yourself. See [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). This will help others have the same question later. Cheers! :-)

Answer (score -1):

My last message had a wrong URL (duplicated URL). The following has the corrected one:

I have finally created a small sample program (WCF service and UWP app) that actually works. If someone needs to do the same thing, you need to following this tutorial https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734712(v=vs.110).aspx to learn how to write a WCF Windows Service Library (needs a host program) that works with console application, and then following this web page https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733766(v=vs.110).aspx to learn the way to convert it into a WCF Web Service Application running under IIS and work with UWP. Remember to update the service-reference of the app whenever you change the configuration of the WCF service.